# Why is my latest question have close vote and downvotes?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I see close votes and downvotes on my [last question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253539/are-these-phrases-and-use-of-words-in-this-paragraph-grammatically-correct). Is it not allowed to ask here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have asked too many questions about your paragraph. That makes the issue too localized to your case. In Stack Exchange, we often try to build a library of information that will aid future learners who stumble upon that question. That changes the site's purpose from a normal helpdesk, where you'd be able to get one-on-one help from an expert. Thus, we **close posts that ask too many questions at once**, because they're often useful to a single person but never anyone else in the future. This is not restricted to ELL Stack Exchange and is a Stack Exchange policy in general.

What I recommend is you pick the issue that confuses you most, and ask about that. Delete the other questions, or ask them in a separate thread. I don't recommend the latter course of action, because a lot of questions in a short time period about the same paragraph get repetitive and make people frown. Instead, you can probably find a lot of your answers by searching around a little.